# Trying to make a simple C program to take names from the user and display them all

Tags: arrays, c

Trying to make a simple program to take names from the user and display them all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COMPETITOR 16
#define NAME_LENGTH 25

int main(void)
{
    char name[COMPETITOR][NAME_LENGTH];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < COMPETITOR; i++);
    {
    printf("Enter Competitor's name: ");
    scanf("%24[^\n]%*c", name[i]);
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < COMPETITOR; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", name[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, it returns some really annoying results and I can't figure out why.

```
Enter Competitor's name: oheuthere
D







X│∞Ω√⌂
p@
δΩ√⌂






--------------------------------
Process exited after 5.747 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have noticed that if I change the value of `#define COMPETITOR 16` it changes the characters that appear and I'm even getting emoji...

Any help to figure out what's going on would be amazing ahaha since I've followed exactly what the lecturer did and its still wack

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the first `for` statement. Clang gives a warning about this.

Comment: My god that 1 semicolon... cheers ahaha

Comment: `"%24[^\n]%*c"` is weird.  It looks like the `%*c` is just being used to consume the newline.  It would be more typical to write `"%24[^\n] "` to consume all trailing whitespace (eg, any leading whitespace in the next entry).

Answer (score 1):

This for loop `for(i = 0; i < COMPETITOR; i++);` has a semicolon on the end of it, meaning it will not run the block next to it. So with this code you are scanning only the `i` line, witch isn't initialized, and printing trash from the memory after that.